# Expresso Store - Customize the PDF Invoice

Tags: expresso-store

I would like to add a header with the company information and logo to the top of the pdf invoice that gets generated. I would also like to eith add this as an attachment or link in the confirmation email that gets sent out after an order is complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think, Expresso Store module module outputs PDF from a view file "order_details_pdf.php" so you can alter this file to add company information at the top.

The view file path is: "expressionengine/third_party/store/views/order_details_pdf.php".

Comment: This is how I've managed to customise the PDF invoice.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off just creating your own invoice using the `{exp:store:orders}` tag. That way you don't need to edit any core files, and you can use a standard EE template to build it. You can also link to it from any of the emails which are sent out.

There's no way to use Store's PDF generator in template tags, so to create the actual PDF your best bet would be to check out some of the PDF generation plugins on Devot:ee.